# "Record Membership Payment" under "Edit Membership" not working after upgrade to 4.7.22

Tags: civimember

Screenshot of results of checking "Record Membership Payment" on upgraded site:
[image: .]

How it should look:
[image: How it should look:]
We recently upgraded to 4.7.22.  Now, if I click "Record Membership Payment", under "Edit Membership", the payment options do not show up.  The same thing happens for members that already have a membership, and I click "Update Payment Status".  I attached a picture of what the screen looks like after checking the checkbox.  I looked in the logs, and do not see any errors.  We are using Drupal 7.56

Comment: Can you compare this with what you see on Demo site so the difference is clear?

Comment: Yeah, I just added a screenshot from our live site, so now you can see the difference.

Comment: i see above that one is New membership and other is Edit membership - but assume that isn't a factor. THere have been some other oddities triggered by having the wrong type of Payment Processor set as default - so just as a random idea, can you unset whatever you have set as default and retry?

Answer (score 1):

There is some complicated logic in CiviCRM related to memberships and payments, especially auto-renewing memberships, and it depends on the payment processor as well.

On one of my 4.7.22 installs for example, it doesn't offer me the opportunity to record a membership payment at all on the edit membership screen, even for non-auto-renewing ones.

My guess is that the upgrade has tightened some of the cases that it thinks shouldn't be used (e.g. an auto-renew membership shouldn't allow you to run an administrative payment via the membership edit screen).

If you can provide details about your payment processor, and also try editing memberships for both auto-renewing and non-auto-renewing, you might get some more useful clues.

On the other hand, the fact that it's giving you that checkbox, but not providing an opportunity to input details when you check it, should be considered a bug.